# Serving MP4 files to HTML5 video, suitable tool, on Linux?

Tags: linux, video, http

I am serving some large MPEG4 files internally, via Apache http, and I am finding that the Chrome browser will try redownloading the whole video every time I scrub through the timeline. Is there any software that will deal with serving video that doesn't result in the whole download being initiated again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffserver](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html), which is installed with FFmpeg.

> ffserver is a streaming server for both audio and video. It supports several live feeds, streaming from files and time shifting on live feeds. You can seek to 
>   positions in the past on each live feed, provided you specify a big enough feed storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving very large files that take long enough to download where a connection risks being severed, then use a synchronization tool like Dropbox, Google Drive, Amazon Drive for teams.  That can cost money to set up, OR you can store them in an [Amazon Web Services S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket and have users download them with the [AWS Command Line Tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html).  Those tools handle shaky connections very well.